# React rerending on updating state from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, class, render

I have a `Question` component and I receive callback `finish` when the question is finished. I want to show loading when I run operations from the finish function. But When I try to `setState({isLoading: true})`, It's been called repeatedly.

I am using the Class component. and here's the Question component I have used.

```js
<QuestionCard
    questionData={question}
    next={this.next}
    previous={this.previous}
    finish={this.finish}
/>
```

And the finish function is as -

```js
finish = () => {
   console.log('Finish')
   this.setState({isLoading: true})
}
```

So When I update the state of `isLoading`, it seems the component is re-rendered, and the finish function is called continuously. How I can stop this to work once and my loader to start loading?

I know there are some other questions also like this but those are not solving my issue. So please suggest solution for this.

Comment: Can you show the whole component were finish is created and pass down, as well as how it is called in the QuestionCard component. We like information to answer the question.

Comment: use functional component. for class components use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: @lvo - there are multiple questions and my 'QuestionCard' component is being repeated as the number of questions. Basically the problem is I want to setState but don't want the component to re render.

Comment: can you perhaps create a codesandbox, the information you have given us is not enough to help to find out what the issue may be.